# Adding an active state to a Jquery background position animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to add an active state to my jquery animation navigation menu but cant seem to get it to work. The animation works perfectly but I need it to stop animation on the active tab (current page in website) and continue to work on the others and so on. Please Help
here is my code

html:

```
<div id="insideNav">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="media.php">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="overview.php">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.php">Mobile</a></li>
        <li><a href="options.php">Options</a></li>
        <li><a href="order.php">Order</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
ul#nav {
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
ul#nav li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;    
}
ul#nav li a {
    display:block;
    width:108px;
    height:76px;
    padding:15px 0 0 0;
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
    font: italic 16px Georgia,"Times New Roman", serif;
    color:#919090;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: url("../images/dropDown.png") 0 -149px no-repeat;   
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    background: url("../images/dropDown.png") 0 0 no-repeat;    
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#nav li a").addClass("js");
    $("ul#nav li a").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 200);
        $(this).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -5px)"}, 150);
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -149px)"}, 200);

      }

    );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery not() function and add a class active for the current page, like

```
$('ul#nav li a').not('.active').hover( ...
```

And so on...

Then assuming your current page is media add a class for that:

```
<li><a href="media.php" class="active">Media</a></li>
```

To completely remove hover set css:

```
ul#nav li a.active:hover { background-position: 0 -149px; }
```

Comment: Thanks @jtheman that kind of worked, It gives me a static image like i want on the active page but when i hover over it again it reanimates. Sorry i am fairly new to this, if you can elaborate on the code a little more. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Are you sure it reanimates not just the css hover state ul#nav li a:hover